# How to generate 100,000 random samples (1D) from 2 PDFs?

Tags: matlab, random, normal-distribution

Can anyone help me how to write a MATLAB code to generate 100,000 random samples (1D)?

The samples should follow 2 PDFs:

1. `N(+1, 0.5)`
2. `N(-1, 0.5)`

where the notation `N(µ,σ)` indicates a [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with mean *µ* and standard deviation *σ*.

Comment: Do you mean: generate 50.000 samples with PDF (1) and 50.000 with PDF (2)?

Comment: If you have the statistics toolbox, have a look at [`normpdf`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/normpdf.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use the randn() function and substitute in mean and standard deviation as follows

```
mu + stdev.*randn(100,1)
```

For more information, check out the matlab help for randn()

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use MATLAB's [Probability Distribution Objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/working-with-probability-distributions.html) which make working with probability distributions very easy.

Note this solution requires the *Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox* to use  [`makedist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html) and [`random()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.random.html).

```
% MATLAB R2018b
% Define probability distribution objects
pd1 = makedist('Normal',1,0.5');
pd2 = makedist('Normal',-1,0.5');
% Generate Samples
X1 = random(pd1,100,1);
X2 = random(pd2,100,1);
```